# Is (or will be) the use of familiar template syntax in lambda expressions allowed?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++14

C++14 introduced generic lambdas. While skimming through the related proposals I found [**N3418**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3418.pdf) by **Faisal Vali, Herb Sutter and  Dave Abrahams**.
Therein section 2.2 is titled :

> 2.2 Allow the use of familiar template syntax in lambda expressions

and the following code examples include snippets like this one

```
[]<int N>(int (&a)[N]) {}
```

Since such things fail to compile (with gcc, clang and Visual Studio), some questions come up :

- Is this an implementation issue ?
- What stopped this part from being accepted ?
- Which is the proposal that finally brought generic lambdas into the language ?

Comment: Also see: [How does the standards committee indicate the status of a paper under consideration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31033130/1708801)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of the paper that was accepted was `N3649`, we can see this by going to Evolution Working Group(*EWG*) [Completed Issue 16:  N3649, N3560, N3559, N3418 Proposal for Generic (Polymorphic) Lambda Expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3737.html#16):

> Reviewed by EWG in Portland 2012, proceeding with a follow-up paper.
>
> Accepted into the Working Draft in Bristol 2013, as N3649.
>
> Bristol 2013: Do not re-open proposals 2.1 and 2.2 in N3560, they are
>   considered NAD. The proposals 2.3 and 2.4 are covered by N3649.

Note this references proposal `2.1` and `2.2` as being NAD(*Not A Defect*) and that they won't be reopened. `N3560` was split off from `N3418` which was the main proposal and proposal `2.1` in `N3560` was:

> Allow the use of familiar template syntax in lambda expressions

that paper notes proposal `2.1` was considered controversial:

> We admit that supporting the   full template parameter list  feature
>   has been deemed  controversial (the Portland 2012 straw-poll outcomes
>   were: 7 SF, 5 F, 3 N, 1 A, 1 SA 1 ) by  a few committee members, and
>   therefore conclude this sub-section with some quotes  from a committee
>   member who was not present in the room during EWG's discussion of 
>   this feature in Portland.

and we can see that [N3649](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3649.html) does not contain this proposal my guess from the quote in paper `N3560`:

> "
>   I think we need more than just 
>   auto.    I'm not sure how much more, but I think having just auto would be too limiting
>   ".

was that *auto* was considered sufficient in the end which would be consistent with saying that the proposal is `NAD` meaning the issue it attempted to resolve is not really an issue.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou whoops, fixed that. That is an important link since it links to the other papers I mention.

Comment: I suppose then that the behaviour implemented by gcc4.9j that @forkrul mentions is an extension. Thnx for being thorough, based on this answer I added the language lawyer tag.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou possible it was implemented with the assumption that it would be accepted, I have seen this a few times.

Answer (score 6):

That precise construct that you quote works fine if I compile the following:

```
auto foo = []<int N>(int (&a)[N]) {};
```

with:

```
g++-4.9 -c foo.cpp -std=c++1y
```

However, using `g++-4.8` or `clang-3.6` both fail. Therefore, I would assume that it is an implementation issue. However, I am not familiar enough with the C++14 standard to know why/if it was accepted (for instance, g++ 4.9 supporting it may be non-standard).