# When should I std::forward a function call?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

A code snippet I saw in *Effective Modern C++* has a clever implementation of the [instrumentation rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995693/2567683) to create a **function timer** :

```
auto timeFuncInvocation = 
    [](auto&& func, auto&&... params)
    {
        start timer; 
        std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(
            std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...); 
        stop timer and record elapsed time; 
    };
```

My question is about `std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(...`

- To my understanding, we are actually *casting* the function to its *original* type, but **why is this needed?** It looks like a simple call would do the trick.
- Are there any other cases where we use perfect forwarding to make a function call ?

---

<sup>This looks like a good use case for [the use of familiar template syntax in lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31195156/2567683) in case we wanted to make the timer type a compile time constant.</sup>

Comment: I think it could be because `func` can big function object with a non-const operator().
This way, you avoid pointless copies and you allow mutation of the function object

Comment: The *type* of the expression doesn't change with the cast, but its *value category* does. That's the whole and only [point of `forward`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13219621).

Comment: The intent is to make sure the correct [ref-qualified](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions) overload of `operator()` is chosen.

Comment: The type of func, once in the function, is not an r-value reference anymore (assuming it was when passed in). If it were, every time you'd pass it to a function it would try to move it! That's why `std::forward` is needed.

Comment: @Cameron nothing gets passed to another function here. My question is for this specific context. The reason pointed by Tavian Barnes (and implied by Kerrek) seems convincing

Comment: @Nikos: Ah, sorry, I read too fast. My comment applies to the usual argument passing case, but that's obviously not what you're doing with `func`. Please ignore :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A better description of what `std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(...)` is doing would be *preserving the value category of the argument passed to the lambda*.

Consider the following functor with ref-qualified `operator()` overloads.

```
struct foo
{
    void operator()() const &&
    { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

    void operator()() const &
    { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};
```

Remember that within the body of the lambda `func` is an lvalue ([because it has a name](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html)). If you didn't `forward` the function argument the `&&` qualified overload can never be invoked. Moreover, if the `&` qualified overload were absent, then even if the caller passed you an rvalue `foo` instance, your code would fail to compile.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30dd5a9681054290)

Comment: Would you agree that the `decltype(func)` part is only needed in generic lambdas where no type information is spelled out for `func` ? If that's the case I could write `std::forward<F>(func)(...)` for `template <class F> void Foo(F&& func)` and do the same thing right ?

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou Yes, that would do the same thing

Comment: I didn't understand why this matters until I realized that `func` could be not only a function pointer, a lambda or `std::function` instance, it could be an instance of any class that declares `operator() &&`. Only then it becomes important.