# C++ specialize a lambda for a certain type

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, template-specialization

I was playing around with the lambda "overloading" as presented [here](https://ngathanasiou.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/lambda-hackery-overloading-sfinae-and-copyrights/), and quickly came to the point where I'd find it convenient to create specialized lambda closures. So I was first trial-and-error'ing a bit, with my most promising trial being

```
auto call_for_vector = [] template<typename T> (std::vector<T>) {};
```

However, a later look at the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) showed that neither this nor similar constructs seem to be allowed by the standard.

**What is the reason why such specializations are not supported?**

I know one can obtain this behaviour using SFINAE, but then it's less readable, harder to write and more error prone. Of course one can also simpy write a class with an appropriate `operator()`, but this is soo C++03 :-)

---

---

**What use would be for such a syntax?:**

One example, this would allow for an easy lambda "overload" like in the following code

```
template <class F1, class F2>
struct overload_set : F1, F2
{
    overload_set(F1 x1, F2 x2) : F1(x1), F2(x2) {}
    using F1::operator();
    using F2::operator();
};

template <class F1, class F2>
overload_set<F1,F2> overload(F1 x1, F2 x2)
{
    return overload_set<F1,F2>(x1,x2);
} 

auto f = overload(
         [](auto&& x){ std::cout<<"call by default"<<std::endl;},
         [] template<typename T>(std::vector<T>){std::cout<<"call for vector"<<std::endl;}
         );
```

One can obtain this behaviour e.g. by using SFINAE base on the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251408/2412846), but again ... this sucks.

**Is there an easy workaround to SFINAE for obtaining specific overloads?**

Comment: well I guess you are familliar with std::function, which is the way to work with lasting functions. I guess lambdas are volatile in the sense that the standard wouldn't want you to store them as is

Comment: @David Haim: the above doesn't work with `std::function` either, as it needs a definite signature.

Comment: you can templatetize std::function, `template <class R, class ..Args> std::function<R(Args...)>` you cannot do that with a lambda

Comment: @DavidHaim: yes, one can do `template<typename T>
std::function<void(std::vector<T>)> call_for_vector = [](auto x){};`, that's a variable template. But one needs to specify the type when calling it, e.g. `call_for_vector<double>()`. As far I can see this doesn't help in the scenario above.

Comment: Isn't `[](std::vector<auto>){}` what "concepts" are supposed to support ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: I also tried this and it would make sense to me from the standard excerpt in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17233649/2412846): "For a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function call operator member template (14.5.2) whose template-parameter-list consists of one invented type template-parameter for each occurrence of auto in the lambda’s parameter-declaration-clause, in order of appearance." So when `auto` becomes a template parameter, then `(std::vector<auto>)` could be translated into `template<typename T> operator()(std::vector<T>)`.

Comment: @davidhigh http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Abbreviated_templates

Comment: I'd hate to close this as a dup (since you're reading my blog :P ) but I've been wondering the same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31195156/2567683). Could you maybe rephrase and add "what use would there be for such a syntax", I might have a tiny piece of code that would be of interest

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: Edited. Feel free to mark it what it is, but only after your answer ... your blog is good anyways ;-)

Comment: @davidhigh It's ok now, since you ask the "what for"s apart from the "why"s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of coding may seem superfluous at first but there are some nice properties we can take advantage of. Regarding the post you mention, I was planning on a part 2, where I'd showcase a neat way of **checking whether a type has a specific member** (function or data). Say you want to check for a `serialize` member function; instead of using complicated mechanisms I discovered it gets as easy as :

```
auto hs = overload( 
    [ ](auto&& x) -> decltype(x.serialize(2), std::true_type{}) { 
        return{}; },       // ^^ this guy ^^ 
    [ ](...) -> std::false_type { return {}; });
```

<kbd>[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/680dec640d477be6)</kbd>

The specifics of standardese evolution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31195156/2567683), but the reason I posted this is to advocate for such a syntax which, had we have had it, the above could be *extended* to **allow partial ordering among *"overloaded"* generic lambdas** :

```
auto do_something = overload( 
    [ ]<class X>(shared_ptr<X> x) -> decltype(x.serialize(2), std::true_type{}) { 
        /*do something specific for shared ptrs of X */ return{}; },      
    [ ]<class X>(X& x) -> decltype(x.serialize(2), std::true_type{}) { 
        /*do a generic operation for other types that have serialize*/return{}; },      
    [ ](...) -> std::false_type { /*do nothing*/ return {}; });
```

Comment: ah, yes, so sfinae, but the modern (and shorter) way ...

Comment: could you add the reference to your other answer? I'd give it a hook then, and then let's close this thread in a large celebration as duplicate.

Comment: @davidhigh I have no other answer, I just made a similar q

Comment: sorry, I meant [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195156/is-or-will-be-the-use-of-familiar-template-syntax-in-lambda-expressions-allowe) ... so nobody misses it.

Comment: @davidhigh OK , will do